# FMX Direct 2D Issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey, direct2d

Good afternoon all!

I'm experiencing a rather annoying issue with one of my current projects. I'm working with a hardware library (NVAPI Pascal header translation by Andreas Hausladen) in one of my current projects. This lib allows me to retrieve information from an NVIDIA GPU. I'm using it to retrieve temperatures, and with the help of Firemonkey's `TAnimateFloat`, i'm adjusting the angle on a custom-made dial to indicate the temperature.

As FMX defaults to Direct 2D on Windows, i can monitor the FPS with any of the various "gamer" tools out there (MSI Afterburner, FRAPS, etc).

The issue i'm having is that when i put the system into sleep mode (suspend to RAM/S3), and then start it up again, the interface on my application is blacked out (partially or completely), and nothing on the UI is visibly refreshing. I'm calling the initialization for the NVAPI library regularly and checking the result via a timer, but this doesn't fix the issue. I'm also running `ProcessMessages` and `repaint` on the parent dial and it's children controls (since i can't seem to find a `repaint` for the form or even an equivalent).

I tried various versions of the library, and each one presents the same issue. The next paragraph indicates that this was in fact NOT the issue, and that it's actually the renderer at fault.

I have one solution, but i want to know if there's something more... elegant, available. The solution i have involves adding `FMX.Types.GlobalUseDirect2D := False;` before `Application.Initialize` in my projects source. However, this forces FMX to use GDI+ rather than Direct2D. It works of course, but i'd like to keep D2D open as an option if i can. I can use `FindCmdLineSwitch` to toggle this on/off dependant on parameters, but this still requires me to restart the application to change from D2D to GDI+ or vice-versa.

What's weird about it is that the FPS counter (from FRAPS in my case) indicates that there's still activity happening in the UI (as the value changes as would be expected), but the UI itself isn't visibly refreshing.

Is this an issue related to Direct2D, or a bug with Firemonkey's implementation? More importantly, is there a better method to fixing it than disabling D2D? Lastly, also related, is it possible to "reinitialize" an application without terminating it first (so perhaps i can allow the user to switch between GDI+ and D2D without needing to restart the application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is may be of the issues with FM prior to the update 4 hotfix - 26664/QC 104210
Fixes the issue of a FireMonkey HD form being unresponsive after user unlock - installing this *might* resolve the issue for you.

The update should be part of your registered user downloads from the EDN (direct link http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28881).

Comment: That did indeed fix it thanks to 1-2 lines being changed in `FMX.Canvas.D2D`! Many thanks Paul!

Comment: Pleasure to be of service :-)